# Profile image in Buddypress registration?

Tags: buddypress

I am creating a buddypress site with custom registration form. This form needs to have profile image upload field with preview.

Is there any plugin to help it or any sample code/idea to get it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

Demo : http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/

Download Code: http://atwebresults.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=391